# pandas DataFrame.to_html change negative numbers in html table as red

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas

I have simple pandas DataFrame which I need to convert to html table such like this one

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
                'Col1': ['20180817','20180816'],
                'Col2': [3541, 2547],
                'Col3': [-254, 147],
                'Col4': ['-74.5%', '25.28%']
             })

df_html = df.to_html(index=False, col_space=500)
```

but also need to change color of all negative numbers to red, e.g.

```
<td>-74.5%</td>
```

Is there any simple way, how to do that? Thank you very much for any hint.

Comment: there is an easy way...https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html ...but this works for numbers not strings...Col4 is string

Comment: Do you need this for all columns or only for `Col4`?

Comment: Not only for Col4 but for all columns where is negative sign.

Answer (score 1):

Update your column before converting to html:

```
df['Col4'] = df['Col4'].map(lambda x: f'<font color="red">{x}</font>' if x[0] == '-' else x)
df_html = df.to_html(index=False, col_space=500, escape=False)
```

Result:

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th style="min-width: 500;">Col1</th>
      <th style="min-width: 500;">Col2</th>
      <th style="min-width: 500;">Col3</th>
      <th style="min-width: 500;">Col4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>20180817</td>
      <td>3541</td>
      <td>-254</td>
      <td><font color="red">-74.5%</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>20180816</td>
      <td>2547</td>
      <td>147</td>
      <td>25.28%</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```